# How to run series of values through stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, while-loop, database-cursor

I have a stored procedure that I need to run a list of values through and output into a temp table.

This is the SP: `EXEC [SP_ReturnHTML] @zoneid, 1`

The first value, I assume, will be a variable and the second value will be hard-coded. I am not able to modify this SP, as it is used in other processes, so I need to run these values through the SP via a cursor or WHILE loop. The values only need to be run through once, so a FAST_FORWARD cursor type may be more ideal, based on some preliminary reading on cursors (of which my experience in is extremely limited). This is what I attempted:

```
declare @zoneid int = (select zoneid from #values)
declare list cursor fast_forward
for EXEC [SP_ReturnHTML] @zoneid,1
open list
fetch next from list
```

But when I try to do this, I get the error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'.`

The output of this SP, when using `@zoneid=14105` (and the hard-coded 1 relates to the `fieldgroupid`) looks something like the shot below. For clarity, despite using `@zoneid=14105`, the reason a value of `4054` shows up is due to the way the SP is written, and is intended. The two values relate to a state and county relationship, noted by the first 2 columns, `ParentHeaderId` and `HeaderId`. I opted to use `14105` for the example, because the 3 examples in the #values table only retrieve their secondary value and I wanted to avoid confusion here.

[image]

The values that I need to run through the SP for the `@zoneid` are in a table (which has about 3100 rows), which can be exemplified with the following:

```
create table #values (zoneid int)  
insert into #values 
values
(13346),
(13347),
(13348)
```

So very simply put, I need something like the following as a final product (pseudo code):

```
declare @zoneid INT = (select zoneid from #values)
select * into #results from 
(
EXEC [SP_ReturnHTML] @zoneid, 1
)
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: I can appreciate that, Yitzhak. I have #1 covered. As for #2, I tried to be as clear as possible what it is I'm trying to do, and the reason I don't have an attempt is because I really don't know where to start. My attempt would be pseudo-code at best. #3, I believe that's covered, in that I just need to know how a WHILE/CURSOR plays into running values through an SP. #4 is fair, I'm running SQL Server 2016 SP3.

Comment: Have you considered changing your stored procedure to work on sets instead of scalar input values? Or creating a separate stored procedure that does so? It might be easier to do that when you’ll have to re-work some parts of it anyway to avoid nested insert/exec. We have beautiful things in T-SQL now called table-valued parameters but also if you create a #temp table and then call a stored procedure, that stored procedure can see the outer #temp table. So as suggested if you can be less hand-wavy about what’s going on inside the procedure you may get better help.

Comment: Aaron, not sure what is meant with the "hand wavy" part. I'm trying to keep my question and content of question as simple as possible so that someone trying to help does not have to scour through a hot mess, if that's what you were getting at? My SP is a bit messy, and it calls yet another SP to fulfill a data retrieval. Truly, not trying to be difficult, I just want to be mindful of other's time.

I think the suggestion to use sets is pretty solid. I hadn't considered that approach, so I will look more into it. Thanks!

Comment: I just meant that you haven’t explained what the procedure does or whether it can be changed or cloned to do anything other than take a single input value in a loop. Loops really aren’t what SQL excels at, so if you can make it so that the procedure can process more than one row at a time, that would be better. Hard to suggest how to do that, though, if we don’t know what the procedure does.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
drop table if exists #results 
drop table if exists #Data
go

create or alter procedure [SP_ReturnHTML] @value int, @s varchar(20)
as
begin
  select concat(' value=',@value, '; s = ', @s) 
end

go

create table #Data (value int, county varchar(30))
insert into #Data 
values
(100, 'Baker'),
(101,'Baldwin'),
(102,'Baldwin'),
(103,'Ballard'),
(104,'Baltimore City'),
(105,'Baltimore'),
(106,'Bamberg'),
(107,'Bandera'),
(108,'Banders'),
(109,'Banks'),
(110,'Banner'),
(111,'Bannock'),
(112,'Baraga')

go

create table #results(value nvarchar(200))
declare c cursor local for select value from #Data
declare @value int
open c
fetch next from c into @value
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
  insert into #results(value)
  EXEC [SP_ReturnHTML] @value, '1'

  fetch next from c into @value
end

go

select *  
from #results
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I'm getting an error: An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested. Now I did neglect the first part, as I do not need to make any alterations or create my SP (as it already exists). Maybe I've misunderstood the reason for that section?

Comment: @jw11432 the error is self-explanatory, you are trying to insert the results of an `EXEC` into a temp table here **AND** inside you SP, and you are not allowed to do that. So you need to come up with a different strategy.

Comment: Thanks Dale. It may be self-explanatory for you, but the reason I'm here is because I don't have enough experience with cursors to get very far. So "come up with a different strategy" doesn't get me very far. But to provide more clarity, when I said "I neglected the first part", I meant that I didn't utilize any code except for "create table #results" and down.

Comment: Its not related to the cursor, and googling the error would explain further that you cannot next `insert into exec` statements. Without knowing a whole lot more about your situation, including the details of your SP and details of other users we can't really suggest another strategy for you. But one possibility is creating the temp table before you call the SP, and then in the SP testing whether said temp table exists, and if so inserting into it.